# Prove that communication protocol complexity less than $n\epsilon$

Tags: probability, coding-theory, information-theory

Alice and Bob get as an input words $x$ and $y$, which consist of  $0$ and $1$. Length of $x$ is $n$ and length of $y$ is $2n$. They want to know if the word $x$ is subword of word $y$. For example, word $001$ is subword of word $1100100$. I need to prove that to know this they need to exchange not less than $\epsilon n$ bits and $\epsilon$ doesn't depend on $n$.

As I understand I need to build communication protocol $f(x, y)$, where $f(x, y) = 1$ if $x$ is substring of $y$, $f(x, y) = 0$ otherwise. Than to use method of combinatorial rectangles or method of fooling set to find its communication complexity.

Please, can you explain me how can I find communication complexity of this function? I'm totally confused than try to find out how to do it. I will be gratefull for any hint or explanation.

Comment: Should we add coding theory tag too?

Comment: Thank you! I've added this tag.

Comment: The people on this site may also help http://cs.stackexchange.com/ It would be good to ask there too